# Installing Anaconda on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, anaconda

I am trying to **install Anaconda** on my Ubuntu 20.04.

I downloaded the installer on the [official site](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#linux). Then I run the command:

```
sudo ./Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

And followed the steps in the CLI installer. I set up the installation directory as `/home/myuser/Programs/anaconda3`. At installation finished I closed and opened back the terminal as suggested, but running `conda --version` I get:

> conda: command not found

How to verify the correct installation of Anaconda? What did I do wrong?
Note: I also restarted the OS, the result does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that anaconda  is added to your path environment variable